# List of variable length lists

Tags: python, list

I want to have N lists of different length and refer to them from a list. Is this possible. For example, I can hard code:

```
list1 = [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]
list2 = [1, 4, 2, 1]
list4 = [1, 1, 0]
```

and then refer to them directly, but I would like to be able to call something like `list[1][1]` and get the same thing as `list1[1]` would return or have `list[3][2]` return an error since `list3` is not defined (and thus `list[3]` would have length 0).

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary?  Not really sure what you are trying to achieve / solve here.

Comment: Make a list of the lists and store it in one variable, not many.

Comment: You'll never index `list` because it is a keyword.

Comment: It's not a keyword and you *can* index a list variable by that name, but it's not a good choice of a variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to dynamically create the list of lists and then append to various lists later.

You could try initializing a list like

```
lists = [[] for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Now when assigning elements, you simply do:

```
lists[0].append(value)
lists[2].append(value2)
```

which will add the value to the first sublist within lists, value2 to the third sublist and so on..

---

You can use an approach with dict also.

```
>>> data = {'list%i' % i : [] for i in range(4)}
>>> data
{'list0': [], 'list1': [], 'list2': [], 'list3': []}
```

So you could append items in list this way

```
>>> data['list1'].append(1)
>>> data
{'list0': [], 'list1': [1], 'list2': [], 'list3': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `lists = [list1, list2, list3]` ?

Comment: I would have to predefine `list1`, `list2`, `list3` in this case. I am looking for a way to dynamically create the list of lists and then append to various lists later.

Comment: @Laurbert515 you can dynamically add and remove from `lists`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it would handle the instance in which you attempt to access an undefined list.

```
list_hash = {
    "list1": [0,2,3,4,1],
    "list2": [1,4,2,1],
    "list4": [1,1,0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. But you should not use this

```
list1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
list2=[2,4,5]

def updateList():
  scope=dir() # gets all defined items
  itms=[]
  list={}
  for itm in scope:
    if itm[0:4]=="list": itms.append(itm)
  for itm in itms:
    try:
      indx=int(itm[4:])
      list[indx]=eval(itm)
    except:
      pass
updateList()
```

Now you will have such a list defined as you are searching the entire scope and matching out strings that match your criteria. i.e list1 list2 list4 etc. It won't have list3 and **won't update later if you add list3**

For that, you have to call updateList() this everytime you add a list*. Will be taxing on performance though. And you can improve the performance by excluding already defined vars. :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using another array like following

```
list1 = [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]
list2 = [1, 4, 2, 1]
list4 = [1, 1, 0]
list = [[],list1,list2,[],list4]
print list[1][0]
#Output :- 0
print list[4][1]
#output :- 1
```

So now you would able to access by list.

Maybe it solves your problem and help you.